# Submit button disappears when accessing cookies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cookies

When I try to access cookies using inline php, my submit disappears for whatever reason.

```
    <div id='add_form'>
        <form id='form' method='post' action='reg.do.php'>
            <label for='date'>Date of Charge:</label><input type='text' name='date' id='date' maxlength='10' value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['name']) ? sanitize($_POST['name']) : ''); ?>' ><br>
            <label for='vendor'>Vendor:</label><input type='text' name='vendor' id='vendor' value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['vendor']) ? sanitize($_POST['vendor']) : ''); ?>' ><br>
            <label for='amount'>Amount:</label><input type='text' name='amount' id='amount' value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['amount']) ? sanitize($_POST['amount']) : ''); ?>' ><br>
            <label for='service'>Description of Service:</label><input type='text' name='service' id='service' value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['service']) ? sanitize($_POST['service']) : ''); ?>' ><br>
            <label for='winner'>Winner:</label><input type='text' name='winner' id='winner' value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['winner']) ? sanitize($_POST['winner']) : ''); ?>' ><br>
            <label for='job'>Job Number:</label><input type='text' name='job' id='job' value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['job']) ? sanitize($_POST['job']) : ''); ?>' ><br>
            <input type='hidden' name='user' id='user' value='<?php echo (isset($_COOKIE['cookie_id']) ? sanitize($_COOKIE['cookie_id']) : ''); ?>' >
            <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
        </form>
    </div>
```

If I get rid of that last hidden input field or change the `$_COOKIE` access inside of it to `$_POST`, then the submit button will show up. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you getting any single quotes or apostrophe's back from your cookie values?  That would break the html attribute, and possibly cause the next item to display incorrectly (or not at all).

Comment: I shouldn't as the `$_COOKIE['cookie_id']` should be returning a first and last name that doesn't have any special characters.

Answer (score 1):

See http://php.net/manual/ro/reserved.variables.cookies.php, I think you need to use the htmlspecialchars function on the cookie.

Comment: The `sanitize` function includes `htmlspecialchars` in its filtering process, so it is going through the function before being outputted.

Comment: Could you copy paste the div code from the page source?

Comment: If you open your page, right click and press "Show page source" or something similar, and then do ctrl+f, enter '<div id='add_form'>' and then copy paste that section.

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled display_errors? maybe you have an error in your code so php breaks, like an unclosed **)** in your inline IF condition ;-)

try this...

```
<div id='add_form'>
    <form id='form' method='post' action='reg.do.php'>
        <label for='date'>Date of Charge:</label><input type='text' name='date' id='date' maxlength='10' value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['name']) ? sanitize($_POST['name']) : ''); ?>' ><br>
        <label for='vendor'>Vendor:</label><input type='text' name='vendor' id='vendor' value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['vendor']) ? sanitize($_POST['vendor']) : ''); ?>' ><br>
        <label for='amount'>Amount:</label><input type='text' name='amount' id='amount' value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['amount']) ? sanitize($_POST['amount']) : ''); ?>' ><br>
        <label for='service'>Description of Service:</label><input type='text' name='service' id='service' value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['service']) ? sanitize($_POST['service']) : ''); ?>' ><br>
        <label for='winner'>Winner:</label><input type='text' name='winner' id='winner' value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['winner']) ? sanitize($_POST['winner']) : ''); ?>' ><br>
        <label for='job'>Job Number:</label><input type='text' name='job' id='job' value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['job']) ? sanitize($_POST['job']) : ''); ?>' ><br>
        <input type='hidden' name='user' id='user' value='<?php echo ( isset($_COOKIE['cookie_id']) ) ? sanitize($_COOKIE['cookie_id']) : ''; ?>' >
        <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>
</div>
```

by the way... it's better to use some kind of template engines instead of inline php code.

Comment: They are enabled, and all the bracket and parenthesis pairing seems fine.